# Create table using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create below table from picture using python.

Anyone have idea for splitting and merge cells.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypxsa.png)

Required code for split and merge cells and save as a picture.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Mangesh

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `pandas` module, [the documentation can be found here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

`pandas` supports [Multi Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html), which is exactly what you are looking for.
With this, you can model your data structure in python.

Comment: is it possible using matplotlib ? because I have to do lots of changes in table format in future also most of the option available in matplotlib. Some of changes already done.

Comment: matplotlib is a visualization library and has nothing to do with data manipulation. You surely can use matplotlib to plot your data, but you won't be able to create or change arrays with it. Normally, matplotlib is used together with pandas.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for similar one? plot should like as per image.